# wanderlust: sort threads by newest message in thread

Tags: wanderlust

I know I can use `C-u S date` in the summary view to sort threads in reverse date order, but when I do this Wanderlust uses the date of the first message in the thread instead of the most recent. Sorting by `number` works the same way. This is unhelpful, because it means an old thread that receives a new reply will not be sorted to the top. Is there a way to get Wanderlust to use the latest date in the thread, highest number in the thread, etc. when sorting?